# gnome-terminal broken due to gsettings+libglib

Tags: linux-mint, gnome-terminal, glib, gsettings

I was trying to build the AWN from source, and I installed a bunch of glib/gio dev packages required by libdesktop-agnostic (also built from source) that affect gsettings. 
At some point during this, I rebooted and found that I couldn't launch any gnome-terminal. (Other gnome apps work normally.)

When I use the nemo-extension terminal (that's a gnome-terminal embedded into nemo) I get the following:

```
(gnome-terminal:11314): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'monospace-font-name' from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of glib.
**
ERROR:terminal-app.c:1449:terminal_app_init: assertion failed: (app->default_profile_id != NULL)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I checked 'monospace-font-name' in the schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface' using dconf-editor, here's what gsettings get says:

```
~ $ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface 'monospace-font-name'
'Monospace 10'
~ $
```

No ampersands there.

It seems like having some libglib/gio's installed at once also causes the following related, similar gnome error-quarks that break gnome-notifications:

- [[gnome-control-center] notifications: fix invalid format string | mail.gnome.org](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2014-January/msg01844.html)
- [gnome-terminal: GLib-GIO-CRITICAL messages from gnome-terminal-server | bugs.debian.org](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=744763)

Which are great, but I'm kinda a novice at most of linux's technical-ness and I don't know really how (or, importantly, WHERE) to apply said patches.

Before you ask, I don't know which packages are causing this (there are waaaay too many in the libglib namespace) and I can't easily single them out one at a time without breaking lots of things.
Yes, all my repositories are official and yes, everything is up-to-date and in order as far as I can tell.

Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela (ubuntu 14.04/trusty) running Cinnamon2.6.1.3 amd64 on a Toshiba Satellite p755 (intel, 6gb ram)

(there's nothing of interest in other log files, including .xsession-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem. Exactly the same issues, to the point - I am running Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela (ubuntu 14.04/trusty) running Cinnamon2.6.1.3 amd64; except it's an Asus machine.

I am with you, I want my gnome-terminal back. This is what I did to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

That was it. The problem was that libglib and the other packages were too new to work with gnome-terminal. So a full distro upgrade fixed all the dependencies. This probably happened after a system update and a reboot. Until the system is rebooted, it will still work fine. But only after that it throws the errors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I recently dumped LiMint in favour of a modern kernel, but I never thought to do `dist-upgrade` because I kinda assumed it didn't exist on a Mint system the way `do-release-upgrade` is an Official-Ubuntu-only thing. I'm certain, however, that this would have solved it. :)

Comment: Did you happen to post this question anywhere else? I found very similar question in linux mint and ubuntu forums.

Comment: i think i did so, yes, as well as on the Linux Mint bugtracker

Comment: All my searches around, went back to your posts. That's what kept me bugging and motivated to find a solution.